# Adding Image to the progress bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I am using bootstrap progress bar and the progress bar as it is, is working fine. Now I want to add an image in front of the moving portion of the progress bar and I want that image to move as the bar progresses.

```
<div class="flex-well-container">
                        <div class="well well-lg" style="width:100%">
                            <div class="progress">
                                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
                                    60% 
                                  </div>
                                  <img src="../img/ProgressAvatar.png">
                            </div>

                        </div><!--end well-->

                       <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-play"><strong>Play Now</strong></button>
</div><!--end flex-well-container-->
```

Following are the css classes that I am using

```
.progress{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.flex-well-container{
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
}
/*set the radius of the well to zero*/
.well-lg{
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8E0d.png)
This is how I want my bar to look like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1EUo.png)
this link shows what I am getting

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you replicate your issue in a JSFiddle so I can take a look?

Comment: @EricGoncalves https://jsfiddle.net/ktqkrw9n/ is the fiddle link.
The thing that is required is there in the image that I have shared with the post.

Comment: I have updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktqkrw9n/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make

```
.progress {
    position: relative;
}

.progress img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

and then set `left:` percentage - image width / 2

Answer (score 0):

```
.progress {
  position: relative;
}

.progress img {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(60% - 50px); // percentage - .5 x width of image
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktqkrw9n/3/)